# How to prove sequence has negative values?

Tags: real-analysis

Question: Suppose that a sequence $a_n$ converges to 0.001. Prove that finitely many values of $a_n$ are negative.

I interpreted this to mean that $a_n \text{ converges to } 0.001 \Rightarrow \exists n \in \mathbb{N} : a_n < 0$.

I assumed that if we negate the conclusion, as in $\forall n \ a_n >= 0 $ then I could reach a contradiction that $a_n$ doesn't converge. However, if the sequence were defined like this $a_i$ = 0.001 or $a_i$ = 0.001+1/i then I don't see a contradiction.

Certainly some values could be negative before the sequence is less than epsilon, but that isn't a "must".

The only thing known about $a_n$ is that it converges. What am I missing about this situation?

Comment: I think whomever posed the question considered $0$ a finite number, as in $0$ negative terms is finitely many.

Comment: Or the original question read carefully really asks you to show that _at most_ finitely many values are negative.

Comment: The question posed is word for word the question definition. Theo might be right that 0 is a finite amount, but it certainly seemed like it implied more than 1, but it is the first question in a chapter on sequences so theoretically it shouldn't be that hard.

Comment: You need to show that the sequences has at most finitely many negative numbers, in other words you have to show that all but finitely many terms of the sequence are positive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By convergence, for every $\varepsilon > 0$, there exists an $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that
$$\forall n \in \mathbb{N}, \, n > N, \, | a_n - 0.001| < \varepsilon. $$
Now simply take $\varepsilon = 0.001/2$. Then there exists an $\tilde{N} \in \mathbb{N}$, such that for all $n$ larger than $\tilde{N}$,
$$|a_n - 0.001 | < 0.001/2 \Longrightarrow a_n > 0 \quad \forall n > \tilde{N}.$$
Thus, if $a_n$ is negative somewhere, it can only happen when $n \leq \tilde{N}$, which is finite. (Note that $0$ is also finite)

Comment: Should the second expression be < 0.001 / 2 ?

Comment: It does feel like this is probably the answer and the question was poorly worded. It's from real analysis by jay Cummings section 3.

Comment: By making epsilon smaller than 0.001 you intend to force $a_n$ to be positive right?

Comment: @Hath995 Despite the mis-match of $\varepsilon$s, $\varepsilon = 0.001$ is also sufficient to conclude $a_n > 0$.